# Cassandra Talend Job running via java posing errors

Tags: java, cassandra, talend

I have 3 node Apache Cassandra cluster, where we are doing data loading operations via java prepared statement, while running the job we are facing the following error:

> INSERT INTO "abc" () VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) 
>   is not prepared on /xx.xx.xx.xx:9042, preparing before retrying executing.

Seeing this message a few times is fine, but seeing it a lot may be source of performance problems.

This query is used in a java code where the talend jars are called, which is taking a lot of time to complete the job of data loading

Above error message is showing for all 3 Cassandra nodes in cluster. Below is the environment setup:

- Apache Cassanndra version - 3.8.0
- Talend Version - 6.4
- Apache Cassandra driver - cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0-shaded.jar